# WPF create style binding from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styles, code-behind

I would like to create this styel in codebehind, but I don't know how to set the binding to the datagrid row property.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedColour[0]}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I do it?
Thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a `Binding` object with the same path:

```
Style myStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
myStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new Binding("SelectedColour[0]")));
this.Resources.Add("MyStyle", myStyle);
```